# change database table content with datagridview on real time

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

i address u all cause im a bit confused of what the course of action should be in this scenario.

I want to do the following in a application im currently building, i wish to **show content from a table in my database on a datagridview** i have in my form, and id like **the changes made by the user in this datagridview be also made in the table from the database**.

now i ve read a few articles about databinding but i am not sure if it works for this scenario, or as how to use it since i ve never used databindings before.

Can this be done with bindings, or ***should i just check for changes in my datagridview and send those changes to the database?***.

Thx in advanced for any answer u can give me, i realy need some guidance in this.

Comment: How about proper capitalization and punctuation?

Comment: u should perhaps read more carefully as to se that there is a proper use of punctuation in the paragraph above. Anyways since this is totaly off topic i will not discuss the subject, i apologise for any grammar mistakes on the question.

Comment: No, I was just annoyed that, in addition to presenting a very broad question to which nobody could give you a clear answer, you didn't bother to capitalize your "I," among other things.

Comment: I think the question is perfectly clear and instead of looking for insignifican grammar errors you should practice your reading and comprencion skills. Im just asking if its possible to save changes in a database table with databindings, you could have asked for a clarification instead of being so pretentious. Also if you dont have any intention to participate in a question plz abstain yourself from comments. If my question is not a proper one a moderator will take it out.

Comment: Thx for the apology, I understand your point of view but keep in mind that english is not everyones first language. Although is not an excuse for bad grammar I encourage you to let some of them pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done automatically:

1. Project > Add New Data source > Select Database > select table(s).
2. View > other Windows > Data sources.
3. Go to the Data sources box that shows up > select your table > select DataGridView from the drop-down next to table name > Drag your table to your form's designer.

Now you get exactly what you want, the user can change data in the DataGridView and save the changes to the database with automatically generated binding and (New, Save , Delete ) buttons.